# Installing scala-maven-plugin Manually in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, plugins

I want to build a program which needs ScalaIDE. I couldn't install it from its dedicated update site (http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site/) into eclipse, because it was blocked in our region and I can't use it by any filter broker in Eclipse env. so it seems that its installation is useless. 
I tried some downloaded files from these sites:

http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/4.2.0-vfinal-luna-211-20150928/scala-SDK-4.2.0-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64.zip

https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin

I installed them by using Help> Install New Software>Add>Archive
but I couldn't install non of them, because the following error occurs:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this error? How can I install it manually? Which installation file I should use? Could you give me a link, please? I have little experience in Java programming and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've added some local site that is not configured correctly. first press the "Available Software Sites"  and remove the "cala" entry. check this - http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-127.htm

Answer (score 1):

The zip file on the typesafe URL is a fully functional Eclipse bundle. Just unzip and run, no need to install anything from there.

Comment: Thanks alot, It caused some other errors such as :
---Description Resource Path Location Type
nlptools-stem-morpha_2.9.2-2.4.0.jar of ollie-app build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.2). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page. ollie-app  Unknown Scala Version Problem

Comment: or errors like this:
----Description Resource Path Location Type
More than one scala library found in the build path (E:/Eclipse-NEW-Scala/eclipse/plugins/org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c.jar, C:/Users/asus/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.2/scala-library-2.9.2.jar).At least one has an incompatible version. Please update the project build path so it contains only one compatible scala library. ollie-core_2.9.2  Unknown Scala Classpath Problem

Comment: Since alot of my projects are in the previous environment, I need to solve the mentioned problem. Any help about that is highly appreciated.

Comment: Scala libraries are not binary compatible. Your project is based on Scala 2.9.2, but the Eclipse IDE supports only Scala 2.10.x and Scala 2.11.x. Scala 2.9.x is probably 4-5 years old by now, so... You may have better luck building on the command line. Does your project use Sbt or Maven?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It uses Maven.